# FacebookConnectPlugin. login returns error "Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request"

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using [phonegap-facebook-plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin), when I run the code below I got an odd error. I have this problem only on Android.

> Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session
> that has a pending request

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(
  ["public_profile"],

  data => {
    // Success callback
  },

  err => {
    // Fail callback

    console.log("Error:", err); 
    // Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request
  }
);
```

I use:

- com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect 0.11.0
- cordova 4.1.2
- Android 5.*

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just the other day, though I was using `facebookConnectPlugin.api("me/albums?fields=id,photos{images,album}", ["user_photos"],`

I ended up logging into the developer side of facebook and had to get the app approved to use `"user_photos"`. I read somewhere they said that if you are not testing with a developer account while still in developer mode it will cause problems like this.

Also if you do not need to request permissions try passing it null.